# What is the expression to express "you are asking a person, who hurt you or you want to hurt him, to wait before you punish him"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Is the phrase "**Well, Just You Wait!**" used to ask a person, who hurt you or you want to hurt him, to wait before you punish him?

I found that phrase in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well,_Just_You_Wait!) which is the title a a Russian film about a hare and a wolf.

The wolf tried to catch the hare but the hare always escaped and hut the wolf so badly that the wolf said "**Well, Just You Wait!**" at the end of the film.

Similar to "**Tom and Jerry**"

I am not sure if we can say "**wait there!**" or "**wait for me!**" or something like that

Comment: The defiant utterance "**Just you wait**!" is normally something only *children* say - if they think they've been bullied / badly treated (cf "**I'm telling on you**!"). In practice it's usually an idle threat, and it certainly doesn't carry any implication of the addressee "holding / hanging on" in expectation of the coming "retribution". An adult is more likely to say something like "**You'll pay for that**!" in the same or similar contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase  "Well, Just You Wait!" means simply that you should expect retribution or revenge for what you have just done. It's similar to "You'll see!".

Your suggestions for alternatives don't have the same sense at all.

Comment: The sense is "Don't think you've got away with it! Punishment/revenge is coming" rather than a literal instruction to wait for something.